# Detecting server pre-rendering in Blazor server app

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, prerender

Is there any way to detect the pre-rendering is going on in a Blazor component from the `OnInitializedAsync` life cycle method? I know the component workflow would call `OnInitializedAsync` called two times, the first time for the pre-rendering and the second time for actual rendering. Finally, called the `OnAfterRenderAsync` method in a single time for actual rendering.

But, I need to detect the pre-rendering in `OnInitializedAsync`. So that I could make some changes in pre-rendering and prevent it in actual rendering vice versa.

I checked the below GitHub issue, but it doesn't have a valid solution. I hope, it should be addressed in an API like `IsPrerendering`.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17282

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no API built in, but you can use the HTTP context to detect it.

I have wrapped this up in a nuget package here

https://www.nuget.org/packages/PreRenderComponent

Update:

Since this time, things have changed and, while there is still no api for detecting this, you should only perform external calls (like JSInterop and HTTP calls) once OnAfterRender/OnAfterRenderAsync has been called.

If you stick to this pattern, you don't ever need to know about pre-rendering status.

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Mister Magoo :-) It helps me a lot.

Comment: This is a terrible answer. Please look at my answer below. (using the IJSRuntime)
There is no guarantee of the state of the HttpContext after the pre-rendering and first rendering. As such, it may works most of the time, but sometimes it may not work, as you are fetching the HttpContext of another request entirely.

Comment: This is an answer from a very different version of Blazor - look at the date.  Also note the update that says things have changed since it was written. Your answer has no better guarantees - using OnAfterRenderAsync and checking the firstRender property is the guaranteed way.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.HasStarted property to check whether the application is pre-rendering or not.  HasStarted specifies that the response header has been sent to the client. If HasStarted is set to false, it means that the application is still pre-rendering and client connection is not yet established.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a WASM project, you can do this:

```
@using System.Runtime.InteropServices

var isPrerendering = RuntimeInformation.ProcessArchitecture != Architecture.Wasm;
```

Answer (score 0):

If server-rendering, you can check if javascript is available.

```cs
public static bool IsPreRendering(this IJSRuntime runtime)
{
    // The peculiar thing in prerender is that Blazor circuit isn't yet created, so we can't use JSInterop
    return !(bool)runtime.GetType().GetProperty("IsInitialized").GetValue(runtime);
}
```

The accepted response (using the HttpContextAccessor) is a terrible advice. There is no guarantee as to what the HttpContext is after the pre-rendering and rendering. As such, you can't rely on it. Sometimes it will work, sometimes not.

If there is lots of traffic, the HttpContext will probably refer to some other unrelated request.

Comment: What happens in your code when `runtime` is null?

Comment: Never happened to me

Answer (score 0):

In 2024, this issue is still lurking around the corner. So here's my approach to dealing with the matter.

**Note: I am using Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.9.2 with the latest  .NET 8 Blazor Web App template.**

Let's create a wrapper component that determines how often a given component has been rendered. This wrapper has two parameters:

```
@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public Type Component { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

Since the wrapper will be initialized twice, we need a static counter for the target component type (a dictionary is a great choice). Each time the wrapper is initialized, we increment that counter. After the first render, we set the counter to the value 2 to avoid overflowing the static integer value. Once we know the wrapper is no longer pre-rendering, we render the child content.

Here's the code for the wrapper component:

`NoPrePrender.razor`

```
@*
    This component ensures that the child content
    is rendered ONCE after pre-rendering is done.
*@
@if (IsNotPreRendering)
{
    @ChildContent
}
else if (PreRendering != null)
{
    @PreRendering
}
@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public Type Component { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? PreRendering { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback OnPreRendering { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback OnRendered { get; set; }

    private static System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<Type, int> State = new();

    private int InitCount
    {
        get => State.TryGetValue(Component, out var value) ? value : 0;
        set => State[Component] = value;
    }

    private bool IsNotPreRendering => InitCount != 0 && InitCount % 2 == 0;
    private bool IsPreRendering => InitCount == 0 || InitCount % 2 != 0;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (Component != null)
        {
            InitCount++;
            if (IsPreRendering && OnPreRendering.HasDelegate)
            {
                await OnPreRendering.InvokeAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            InitCount = 2; // avoid perpetual incrementing and trouble down the road
            if (OnRendered.HasDelegate)
                await OnRendered.InvokeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

In another component (e.g., Home.razor), you can now use this wrapper component as shown below:

`Home.razor`

```
<NoPreRender Component=typeof(Home) OnPreRendering=@(() => Console.WriteLine("Pre-rendering..."))>
    <AuthorizeView>
        <Authorized>
            <Redirection Url="/admin-dashboard" Delay="2000" Message="Redirecting to the dashboard..." />
        </Authorized>
        <NotAuthorized>
            <Login />
        </NotAuthorized>
    </AuthorizeView>
</NoPreRender>
```

Make sure to replace the content with what makes sense to you.

Answer (score -1):

To detect pre-rendering on Blazor server, I recommend to act according to the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0), here is quote:

> Blazor Server apps that prerender their content call OnInitializedAsync twice:
>
> - Once when the component is initially rendered statically as part of the page.
> - A second time when the browser establishes a connection back to the server.

> To prevent developer code in OnInitializedAsync from running twice, see the [Stateful reconnection after prerendering section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0#stateful-reconnection-after-prerendering).

Answer (score -1):

I'm adding static bool field "**ClientClass.PrerenderMode = false**" to the SomeClient class

A have

- Host (depend: client)
- Shared
- Client

client did not set bool.

on server "**_Host.cshtml**" `@{ ClientClass.PrerenderMode = true; }`

PS: If you have net core server with Blazor Webassembly